# Pickle in Python, how to check if variable is a string or a pickle?

Tags: python, string, types, pickle, isinstance

I send and receive different objects through the network. In my application the server can receive a pickle or a string. Is there any way of knowing if the data I got is the pickle or a string?

I tried:

```
class C:
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":

    c = C()

    data = pickle.dumps(c)
    key = 'cryptokey'

    print isinstance(data, basestring)
    print isinstance(key, basestring)

    print type(data)
    print type(key)
```

But the output is not helpful, it shows:

```
True
True
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
```

So it seems it treats the pickle and the string the same. Any ideas?

Comment: A pickle is a bundle of binary data as a string.

Comment: Change your data format to be less ambiguous.

Comment: Pickle starts with a specific protocol and version tag. But much more sensible - annotate your data so the receiver knows if what they got was a pickle, a string or a cucumber.

Comment: @pvg: Only protocols 2 and up have that tag.

Comment: @user2357112 which is the default.

Comment: @pvg: Only on Python 3, which isn't the version used for the example code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    pickle.loads(key)
    print 'Pickled data'
except:
    print 'Not a pickled data'
```

Comment: This gives false positives for any string that looks like a pickle but wasn't intended to be one. For example, `'N.'`.

Comment: Also, it lets people execute arbitrary Python code, such as `__import__('os').system('email my database to Nigeria')`, if they can affect the contents of the message just right.

Comment: That's the issue of pickle, whenever you are loading the data it would be the case, not just here.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3 this is no longer the case as the result of `pickle.dumps` is not a bytes object:

```py
In [1]: import pickle                                                    

In [2]: test = 'mystring'                                                

In [3]: pickle.dumps(test)                                               
Out[3]: b'\x80\x03X\x08\x00\x00\x00mystringq\x00.'

In [4]: isinstance(_3,str)                                               
Out[4]: False
```